# Unable to compile the JSP in Tomcat 7.0.23 But it can run in Tomcat 5.5.28

Tags: jsp, tomcat, struts

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>   An error occurred at line: 695 in the jsp file: /pages/settings/viewModify.jsp
>   ecViewChildSelItr cannot be resolved

The `ecViewChildSelItr` is the `id` attribute of `<logic:iterate>` in `viewModify.jsp`.

```
<logic:iterate id="ecViewChildSelItr" name="customReportForm" property="getEcdisplay" type="database.EcViewChild">
    <option value="<%=String.valueOf(ecViewChildSelItr.getEcdisplay().getEcDisplayId()>
```

This runs in Tomcat 5.5.28, but not in Tomcat 7.0.23. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't knwo why it doesn't compile, but if you respect the best practices and avoid using scriptlets, you won't have this problem:

```
<option value="${ecViewChildSelItr.ecDisplay.ecDisplayId}">...
```

Also note that `<logic:iterate>` is deprecated (as are nearly all other logic tags) in favor of the JSTL `<c:forEach>` tag (and other core JSTL tags) for years.